# Show that x'X'y=y'Xx

Tags: linear-algebra, transpose

Can anyone prove the following

x'X'y = y'Xx

Where x,y is a column vector and X is a (n x k) matrix.

---

I mean its obvious when the above is a quadratic form, but less so when it is a bivariate function.

Comment: @ Cheuk , clearly, it is a homework and you have not thought about it.

Comment: @loup blanc, This is not a homework. I saw it in one of the OLS estimator derivation but I should have given it more thought. Sorry for asking silly question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $A = x'X'y$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix, so $A = A'$.

Comment: Oh, I am so stupid! Thanks!